# Generating e value in RSA Encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

I've generated p,q,n, and totient, and need to generate e where `1 < e < totient` and `e` and `totient` are coprime. The problem I'm running into with my code is that I'm first generating totient (normal `(p-1)*(q-1)` way) but when i try to generate a coprime e, it usually runs forever with this code

```
const mpz_class RsaKeys::compute_e(mpz_class totient) const {

  dgrandint e(bits_);
  while ((e.get_mpz_class() < totient) ||
     !is_coprime(e.get_mpz_class(), totient)) {
 std::cerr<<e.get_mpz_class()<< " is not coprime with "<<totient<<std::endl;
 e.reroll();
}
return e.get_mpz_class();
```

I'm testing with low bit integers 8-32, and will actually need to handle 1024 bit values, but I need a way to first check if the `totient` generated has any arbitrary number of possible values that would make it coprime. I have only found ways of checking whether values are coprime, but not if there exists a complementary coprime value for a number that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `e` doesn't need to be random, indeed most RSA systems use one of a small number of common `e` values, with the most widely used being 65537.

Comment: if every time i'm generating a new key which i start by generating random prime values p and q, how can I have a set of consistent e's?

Comment: Much of the security of RSA is derived from the difficulty in factoring the modulus, not the choice of exponent. If you have a look at something like OpenSSL, when generating RSA keys you get to choose whether to have `e` = 3 or 65537 (the latter being generally considered the more secure choice, as there are attacks on RSA that exploit low public exponents, e.g. [Coppersmith's Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack#Low_Public_Exponent_Attack)).